# Probability of a word being incorrectly decoded.

Tags: coding-theory

Let C be the ternary repetition code of length 4 over the alphabet $\{0,1,2\}$.

If the probability of each symbol being wrongly received is t and each symbol is likely the probability of a word being incorrectly decoded is $t^2 (3-2t)$

I do not understand how to get this answer and this is the working in the solutions which I dont understand.

I know the formula in the binary code of length n,

p(exactly i errors in specified positions ) = $t^i (1-t)^{n-1}$

Why is P$($ $1$ being received $)$ $=$ $1-t$? How is this calculated?

Why is P$($ $o$ or $1$ being received $)$ $=$ $t$ How is this calculated?

Why do we then say

P$($ $0$ being received)= p$($ $2$ being received$)$=$\frac{1}{2}t$ ?

We then get $(1-t)^4 + 8(\frac{1}{2} t) (1-t)^3 + 12 (\frac{1}{2}t^2 (1-t)^2$

Where do the coefficients come from?

I understand we then simplify the terms to get $(1-t)^2 (1+2t)$ and the final answer is obtained by doing $1-(1-t)^2 (1+2t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're looking at part (b) of Exercise 6 in [this collection of solved problems](http://www.famnit.upr.si/sl/resources/files/knjiznica/studijsko-gradivo/epasalic-studijsko-gradivo-zbirka-nalog-linear-codes.pdf). If so, you have to view your question in the context of part (a), which is about sending the word $1111$.

The solution to part (a) lists all the words that will be correctly decoded. There is one word ($1111$) with no errors, there are eight with exactly one error, and there are 12 with exactly 2 errors. To compute the probability of correct decoding, you add up the probabilities of each of these words. This explains the coefficients $1, 8, 12$.

As for your remaining questions: By assumption, $t$ is the probability of a symbol being wrongly received, so for any specified position in the word $1111$, $$P(\mbox{1 is received}) = 1 - P(\mbox{1 is wrongly received}) = 1-t.$$ Moreover, if $1$ is not received, then either $0$ or $2$ is received, so for any specified position in $1111$,
$$P(\mbox{0 or 2 is received}) = P(\mbox{1 is wrongly received}) = t.
$$
Now, assuming the author meant 'each *incorrect* symbol is equally likely', you argue that $P(\mbox{0 is received}) = P(\mbox{2 is received})$ and therefore each of them is equal to $t/2$.

Comment: Where do we get $(1-t)^4 + 8(\frac{1}{2} t) (1-t)^3 + 12 (\frac{1}{2}t^2 (1-t)^2$ from, where do the powers come from?

Comment: If there are zero errors in the word, then every symbol was received correctly so the word has probability $(1-t)^4$. For each word that has one error, the symbols that were correctly received have prob $1-t$ while the symbol that was wrongly received has prob $t/2$, so the word has probability $(1-t)^3(t/2)$. Similarly, for each word that has two errors, the prob of the word is $(1-t)^2(t/2)^2$.